# How to filter wildcard in string using mule filters

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have value /asdf. I'd like to split the '/' from the string.

How this can be achieved using mule filters?

Comment: What do you need to do? Filter messages containing '/asdf'? Split the '/asdf' message into '/' and 'asdf'? Remove '/' from '/asdf'?

Comment: I need to filter slash(/) from the string . If I give the input as /asdf means my output should contain only asdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I correctly understood your question, but to define a wildcard filter that matches both "asdf" and "/asdf" in Mule you need just `<wildcard-filter pattern="*asdf"/>`

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Using+Filters#UsingFilters-WildcardFilter

Comment: I need to filter only the slash from my input.

Comment: OK, so you are talking about changing the payload from "/asdf" to "asdf", not filtering as in the above documentation? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    <flow name="test">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" path="in"/>
        <scripting:transformer>
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
                def p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^/(.*)")
                def m = p.matcher(message.getPayload())
                if (!m.find()) throw new IllegalArgumentException('Message does not start with /')
                return m.group(1)
            ]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:transformer>
</flow>
```